# Laravel 5.3 Redirect User after Registration

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and the php artisan command `make:auth` to scaffold the registration and login. After a user registers, I want to redirect him to a page that says something like "Verify your email" and I don't want it to automatically login the user like default.

I can only think of, in the `create()` method in the RegisterController, instead of returning the User(I assume that's where it automatically logins), I want to redirect to another view.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new Company($confirmation_code));

    User::create([
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'email' => $data['email']
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('verifyemail');
}
```

But I get this error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 32 and defined`

I tried to override the `register(Request $request)` method in the RegistersUsers.php to take out the line that makes the logins, but it's still not working.
Any ideas?

EDIT:I added `$this->guard()->logout();` to the overrided `register` method after it does the login. It works, but it's not the correct way to do this and I would like to find another solution..

Answer (score 0):

I would create your own register controller for more flexibility. And in their make the create/store method that creates and then redirects to the place you want. Wouldn't take too long

Comment: That sounds like an unnecessary workaround.. There has to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController add this after Method create:

```
public function redirectPatch() 
{
  return "verifyemail";
}
```

**Exemple**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new Company($confirmation_code));

    User::create([
        'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'email' => $data['email']
    ]);

}
public function redirectPatch() 
{
  return "/verifyemail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For weeks I have been trying to find a solution for this.
To override the default URL after registering, just add inside the create function the following:

```
$this->redirectTo = '/url-after-register';
```

Just like this

```
protected function create(array $data) {
    $this->redirectTo = '/url-after-register';

    return User::create([...]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I have implemented your solution. Or you can override registered method in your class and redirect to your specific route.

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    return Redirect::route('your.route');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods in your RegisterController.php

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ConfirmationEmail($user));

    return back()->with('status', 'Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.');
}

public function confirmEmail($confirmation_code)
{
  User::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->firstOrFail()->hasVerified();
  return redirect('login')->with('status', 'You have successfully verified your account. Please Login.');
}
```